# Qt5 Mediaplayer Example Error

Tags: media-player, qt5

needing your help as in I’m using qt5 and it has a in inbuilt media player example so what happens is when i play an example video which has a codec of H.264 is giving me Error as follow::

Warning: "No decoder available for type 'video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)avc, alignment=(string)au, level=(string)3.1, profile=(string)main, codec_data=(buffer)014d401fffe10023674d401f967200800936028100000e100002bf203460016e40016e45ef7c1e1108a24001000468de3c80, width=(int)1024, height=(int)576, framerate=(fraction)25/1, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1'."

g-streamer is available in my Ubuntu 14.04

So is there any suggestion ?

Answer (score 2):

An extra repository is needed in Ubuntu to correctly decode videos.
try this, it's work for me :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/trusty
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-libav
sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg
```

Comment: That ppa no longer exists

Answer (score 2):

The solution for me was simply:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```